# ediff from within magit-diff lost in v2.1

Tags: magit

magit-diff displays a buffer, which lists all files, which differ between the two revisions one is looking at. In v1.4 it was possible to type 'e' on each of these lines or inside the diff part to call magit-ediff for this file. Somehow this functionality seems to have disappeared in v2.1. Is there any way to resurrect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*At the time this question was asked, dwimming did not work inside `magit-diff-mode` buffers. The problem wasn't in Magit's Ediff code, all the necessary bits were there, but the low-level function `magit-diff-type`, which is also used by a lot of other code, was a bit lazy inside `magit-diff-mode` buffers and just said `undefined`. Anyway...*

You can initiate an Ediff session from within a `magit-diff-mode` buffer now. `magit-ediff-dwim` should be able to determine what Ediff variant should be used. It detects when to use a staging session and when to use a compare session. If point is on a file, then it will a create a session for that file.  Otherwise it will ask for a file (unfortunately all files will be offered as completion candidates, not just those that were modified in the range).

---

If that doesn't match your experience, then please let me know.

Comment: The key was certainly "e". And the new "e" still does three windows instead of 2 like the old one did.

Comment: @abo-abo I'm positive the old one also did three windows merge. Not that I like it that way, but I think it was configurable (maybe?).

Comment: The old one does a two window diff, not a merge. I know for sure, since I'm still using the old one. And there's no way to configure it: I've opened an issue a month ago, but it was closed without a solution.

Comment: The feature was not really improved for that use case from magit-diff. You can choose compare then, but you have to type in the revisions and files by hand, although they could be determined from the diff. This makes it very cumbersome to use the current ediff approach from within magit-diff.

Comment: @abo-abo I was wrong about the key binding. But the claim about your issue being closed without a resolution is a bit insulting. I have implemented the feature you asked for, even though I still think it is clearly interior. Now all you have to do is bind a key to these variants. You neither thanked me for that, or else explain what is wrong with that implementation. Frankly it's you who just tuned out.

Comment: @Martin Ah, indeed you have to manually insert the revisions in that case. That could probably be addressed fairly easily - I will look into it. Meanwhile if you just want to look at the changes in a single commit, then instead visit that using `RET` (instead of `d d`) and then `e` from the `magit-revision-mode` buffer.

Comment: @tarsius, basically what Martin said. The variants you implemented are all inferior to the old behavior, just like the current default behavior is. I don't mean to insult, I just tell it how it is.

Comment: And I still feel the new implementation is vastly superior. It might have defects - here we just found one - but these can be fixed.

Comment: And have you *actually tried* the variants I have implemented just for you?

Comment: It's a bit insulting that you think I didn't try them. `magit-ediff-show-unstaged` and `magit-ediff-show-staged` both prompt for a file. This is redundant, since I always want file at point, and it's always clear if it is staged or unstaged, so there's no need for two functions.

Comment: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1743 https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1883